# Search listboxitems in wpf

Tags: wpf, tags, listboxitem

I have a task to attach few tags with a listbox item in WPF and later do a search on these tags to find the associated listboxitem.
I am reading tags from an external XML file so I need to attach these tags programmatically. 
I see that there is one property Tag for a listbox item but i am not sure if we can attach more the one tag and if WPF allows searching of a listbox item depending on its tag.

Comment: Dude, I really wish I had the ability to ban you from StackOverflow and prevent you from posting these non-questions. 1 - WPF is not winforms, If you need to search, search DATA, not UI. 2 - Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting questions in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The `Tag` property is of type `object`, so if you want to hold multiple objects in there, just use a collection, because collections are still `object`s:

```
ListBoxItem.Tag = new List<object>();
```

However, as @HighCore as correctly mentioned, you *don't* want to do this on the UI objects, because this is WPF... we work with the data. So instead of setting your tag(s) into the `ListBoxItem.Tag` property, just define your own class to hold the data and add a `Tag` property to that:

```
YourDataItem.Tag = yourTag;
```

Now that we're correctly working with the data, we can simply iterate over a collection of data items and find those items that have a particular tag:

```
IEnumerable<YourDataItem> results = YourCollection.Where(i => i.Tag == someTagValue);
```